# Simple concept question about the dimensionality of a representation in point group

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, representation-theory

Concept question about the dimensionality of a representation in group theory here:
Look at 3.1(c) of problem set, from *group theory application to the physics of condensed matter* of M.S.Dresselhaus:

> 3.1(c) Given the point group T,verify that the equality
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_j{l_j^2} =h
> \end{align}
>
> What is the meaning of the two sets of characters given for
>   the two-dimensional irreducible representation E?

It seems that E with 2 sets of characters is called two-dimensional irreducible representation. But when verifying the equality above, where lj should be the dimensionality of the IR Γj, and E is viewed as TWO representations and each has a dimension lj=1(referring to the character of group T and p40 of Dresselhaus's book),so that we have :
\begin{align}
\sum_j{l_j^2} =h \\
1^2+1^2+1^2+3^2 = 12 
\end{align}
 to finish the proof.
Instead of:
\begin{align}
1^2+2^2+3^2=14 \neq 12 
\end{align}

So, **my question is** what is the meaning of a 2 dimension representation? Becoz it seems that there are two definitions of dimension here.

The character table of group T attached here, from Dresselhaus's book
[image: The character table of group T attached here, from Dresselhaus's book]

Comment: The dimension of a representation is the dimension of the vector space on which the group is acting.

Comment: Thank you, can we tell the dimension from the character table? Does it mean the 'E' is a 2 dimensional representation with 2 sets of characters and 'T' is a three dimensional representation with just one set of  characters? But in this case, the equality mentioned above doesn't hold?

Comment: The character of a representation is its trace (each group element corresponds to a linear transformation). As such, the character evaluated in the neutral element is the dimension of the representation.

Comment: You haven't told us what the group $T$ is, so it's very hard to interpret this table.  Re your question in the comment, there is one character associated to each representation.

Comment: @WillO group T is a point group, my question is about the dimensionality of irreducible representation 'E'.

Comment: @doetoe yes I agree with that, but the author says 'E' is a two dimensional representation while on the character table its neutral element is TWO '1'. And if E is two-dimensional, it doesn't coincide with the equality \begin{align}
\sum_j{l_j^2} =h \end{align} mentioned above.That is exactly what I am confused about.

Comment: I cannot tell you the dimensions of the irreducible representations of a mystery group.  If you tell us what the group is, it should be easy to settle this.

Comment: @WillO I am sorry but it seems that I can not catch you. I thought that most information of a group can be found on the character table? The point group T should be unique, for more information you can refer to here [link](http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/character_tables/T.html)

Comment: All the information you need is in the page you linked to.  $T$ is (isomorphic to) the alternating group $A_4$.  This group has no irreducible representations of degree $2$.  There are four irreducible representations, of degrees $1$, $1$, $1$ and $3$.  The four rows of your table correspond to those representations.

Comment: @WillO   I think I need to modify my question,  I am confused becoz the characters of two of the irreducible representations(IR) of degree one, are not orthogonal to each other. i.e. if check the 2 sets of characters of 'E'(in the table the textbook provides) I find that they are not orthogonal to each other, I think that is why we put this two in the same representation 'E'?

Comment: But they *are* orthogonal.  The inner product is $1\cdot 1 + 3 (1\cdot 1) + 4(\omega\cdot \omega)+4(\omega^2\cdot\omega^2)=0$.  (Don't forget that the conjugate of $\omega$ is $\omega^2$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. The point group in question is the [chiral tetrahedral symmetry group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_groups_in_three_dimensions) $T$ of order 12, i.e. the symmetry group of the [tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron).
2. Problem 3.1(c) confusingly talks about a 2-dimensional *irreducible* representation $E$, which is in fact the *reducible* sum of a 1-dimensional representation and its complex conjugate representation.
3. The above 1-dimensional representation assigns a $e^{i\phi}$-phase factor to $\phi$-rotations around one of the four corners of the tetrahedron.

References:

1. M.S. Dresselhaus, G. Dresselhaus, & A. Jorio, *Group Theory: Application to the Physics of Condensed Matter,* 2008.

Comment: Thank you, is there any meaning to put two irreducible representations together as 'E'?